# Multiple resolution videos being composed with AVMutableComposition

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation, avmutablecomposition, avkit

Is it possible to create a video composed of separate videos of different resolutions? I'm taking two different `AVAsset`s that are MPEG4 videos of different resolution (one 300x300 and another 600x600) and using `AVMutableComposition` to compose them together:

```
let composition = AVMutableComposition()

composition.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset1.duration), ofAsset: asset1, atTime: kCMTimeZero)

composition.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset2.duration), offset: asset2, atTime: asset1.duration)
```

When I play back the composition, the part where asset2 should start playing is blank. However, if I change asset2 to a video that has the same resolution as asset1, the composed video works as expected (video from asset1 plays followed by video from asset2).

Comment: It is, but you'll need to look into using a transform on the track to make sure that the videos are scaled into the same output window correctly.

Comment: @TimBull ok, thanks for confirming -- is there some sample code you can point me to that does that?